# Terminator Expected at End of String

Tags: powershell

I am having an issue where I am receiving a terminatorexpectedatendofstring error with the following code that is to be used to delete inactive accounts. Currently I am just testing the logging:

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties accountauditstatus, displayname,    distinguishedname, lastlogondate, lastlogondate, passwordlastset, created,   enabled -SearchBase "OU=Vendors, DC=my, DC=domain, DC=com" |Where-Object {$_.accountauditstatus -ne "ignore: proxy account" -and $_.passwordLastSet –lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) -and $_.created -lt (get-date).adddays(-365) -and $_.lastlogondate -lt (get-date).adddays(-365) -and $_.Enabled -eq $true}|Select-object -First 10 |ForEach-Object {Write-output $_.name |Out-File -filepath c:\temp\log.log -append}`

What is odd is that if I paste the command into a powershell prompt it runs perfectly fine, but when I attempt to run as a .ps1 file, I receive the error. I am not exactly a PowerShell expert, so I am sure there is something I am missing. Any help would be great!

Comment: Assuming you saved everything in one line...I'd start to remove cmdlet by cmdlet to see in which part error is...

Comment: Adriano, thanks for the reply. Yes, everything is on one line. I could certainly try what you suggest, but it is weird that the command runs fine from the prompt, just not as the file.

Answer (score 1):

Going through step by step I found that powershell did not like this line:

```
$_.passwordLastSet –lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
```

I took the

```
-lt (get-date).adddays(-365)
```

From the next spot in the code and copied and pasted it, replacing 365 with 7 and the code worked. Not sure exactly what the problem was, but the code is now working.

Thanks for your suggestion, Adriano.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

In my case, I fixed it by **typing in the command manually** in my .ps1 file instead of copy pasting. Exact same text. Presumably that got rid of some invisible strange characters that were causing the error.

More specifically

I had written a script to cleanup old files in order to free up some space. Something like

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\random\path" -Recurse | Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-15) | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

Copy pasting this directly in powershell worked fine but putting it in a .ps1 file did not and was getting the *missing terminator* error.

All I did to make it work, was to follow the exact location of the error (line and column in error message) and re-write the chunks of the command in exactly the same way.

Error kept shifting to a different location and so I repeated the process until there was no error and script run successfully.